# Return to the beginning of the results of a for loop

Tags: php, categories, loop

I am currently doing a little script (and I am rather beginner), I would like to know how to return to the result number one of a for loop after the table containing the results have been traveled?

here's the code:

```
$currenttPostId = get_the_ID();
$theCategory = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'category');
$prevNext = array();

if (!empty($search_args)) {

    $search_args['posts_per_page'] = -1;


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($search_results); $i++) {
        if ( $search_results[$i]->ID == $currenttPostId ) {
            $prevNext[] = $search_results[$i - 1];
            $prevNext[] = $search_results[$i + 1]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "return to the result number one of a for loop after the table containing the results have been traveled"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Let's say that I have a query that shows me a page of 12 articles, when we click on one of these articles, it brings us back to the single page, on this single page, I created a pagination brings up to the twelfth article and what I would like is that the twelfth article brings me back to the first one when I click on next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantly access any position in an array by specifying the index.

i.e. to get the first element of the $search_results array:

```
$first_result = $search_results[0];
```

*Note if you're not used to working with arrays, they are "0" indexed in most languages, which means the first element's index is 0, the second is 1, etc.*

This is what your loop is basically doing as well. Each time it accesses a different number directly, $search_results[$i] is just putting the value of $i in the same spot as I had the 0 above.

You can **also** change the value of $i in your loop if you want to start the loop over, for instance. Adding the line:

```
$i = 0;
```

...would send you back to the beginning. However I would not recommend you work with the index of a loop until you are quite comfortable with them.